# Div content visible but disabled

Tags: html, css

I have a div with this style:

```
#menudiv{
    width:20%;
    padding:3px;
    float:left;
    height:100%;
    font-family:ubuntu;
    font-size:25px;
    color:#404040;
}
```

The problem is that although the div is placed correctly and has the right visual attributes, the content in this div is *disabled*. As in, the data cannot be selected with click-moving the mouse and the links in this place are unclickable :S

What am I doing wrong here?

P.s. there are two other divs in this section of the page which these styles:

```
#content{
    position:relative;
}

div.sidebar{
    float:right;
    margin-right:25px;
    margin-left:5px;
    padding:5px;
    font-family:verdana;
    font-size:10pt;
    width:300px;
    border:solid 2px #a0b0c0;
    display:flex;
    text-align:justify;
}
```

The content in these divs is normal and can be interacted with.

The content in the div is this:

```
<div id="menudiv">
    <img class="titleico" src="images/home.png" /> &nbsp; &nbsp; HOME<br />
    <ul id="menulist">
        <li><a href="yo">Menu item 1</a></li>
        <li>Menu item 2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

## UPDATE 2

You can check the whole thing @ http://daera.net/daera

The leftmost div (the one with HOME text and 2 list items) has the problem.

Comment: Please Share the html part too..

Comment: show html code or make jsfiddle for this can help you more efficiently

Comment: Edited to add the html content of the div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1

remove this block from the code

```
#contentdiv {
    position: relative;
}
```

Option 2

```
#contentdiv {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 200px; // give what ever required
}
```

issue will be resolved

Answer (score 1):

If your HTML/CSS/Javascript/JQuery code contains the following, please remove them...

```
-moz-user-select: none; 
-webkit-user-select: none; 
-ms-user-select:none; 
user-select:none;
-o-user-select:none;
unselectable="on" 

onselectstart="return false;"
onmousedown="return false;"
```

Comment: None of that is added in my CSS code. The problem is not that I want to make my div unselectable, the problem is that it **is** unselectable and I want to make it selectable.

Comment: Read my whole comment, since you didn't share you code, i had to share this, to make you understand that if such codes are available, remove them. Anyway, then u might wanna check you script files, if they r disabling them.

Comment: I have added the content of the div in my updated version of question statement (in the end)